# How to know if no radio button in a group is checked from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have a group of radio buttons in my .aspx:

```html
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rb1" runat="server" GroupName="rbGroup" Text="RB1" />
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rb2" runat="server" GroupName="rbGroup" Text="RB2" />
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rb3" runat="server" GroupName="rbGroup" Text="RB3" />
 <asp:RadioButton ID="rb4" runat="server" GroupName="rbGroup" Text="RB4" />
```

How can I tell in my VB.NET code if none of them are checked (for example, they were unchecked by JavaScript)?

Comment: Why use 4 separate radio buttons when you could just use a RadioButtonList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have individual RadioButton controls, then you can access each one's Checked property:

```
If Not (rb1.Checked Or rb2.Checked Or rb3.Checked Or rb4.Checked) Then
    ' None were checked.
End If
```

If instead you used a RadioButtonList control, then you could just check whether its SelectedValue property was blank.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set the default button to a radio button with Text=none.
Check if the none radio button is still active at the end of the form.